# Where's the dropdown list of events in Visual C#?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

[This article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/16/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx) mentions the availability of a dropdown of default event handlers in Visual Studio (C#). I can't find it. What is in-line code? I am assuming C# code inside the aspx file? I tried that and there was no dropdown.

Read the line just below the first grey box. I am using VS 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about this panel? This lists all the events for a given control when in the Designer. You can access it by clicking the "Events" button in the Properties panel (see 1). Double-clicking in the field (2) causes Visual Studio to automatically generate a method stub.

[image]

Alternatively, if you're viewing the code, you can type the name of the control followed by "." to activate Intellisense, select the event you want to handle, then type "+=" and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to achieve the same effect.

Comment: There are times when I can't seem to get that Events button to show up. Sometimes clicking outside the control and then back in again fixes it for me.  Sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I thought he was talking about some dropdrop with event handlers for the page and it stubs the handler for you. The one you mentioned is available from the designer and it's available for both C# and VB. He said it shows up when writing inline code.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - See the second part of my response; is that what he's talking about? Typing the name of the control, then typing "." + [the name of the event] + "+=", then pressing `Tab` twice?

Comment: I am going to accept this answer even though I think the article is not about the events dropdown in design mode. he mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

To see the dropdown list with the event's you have to switch to the design view, then open the properties pane. There you will find a toolbar button (a yellow flash), that will display the events of the selected control. By double-clicking an entry, an event-handler is added to the code-behind.

Comment: The poster is referring to the fact that for some reason the "yellow flash" button is not there.  There seems to be a bug in VS that for some reason it doesn't show up when it should.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Events tab randomly appears and disappears in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764590/events-tab-randomly-appears-and-disappears-in-vs-2008)

Answer (score 0):

This and the feature to generate event handlers without having to switch to Design view [is finally coming](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097404) in Visual Studio 2012.