# How can I get Visual Studio to auto-stub delegates to control events in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, delegates, page-lifecycle

So in a WinForm app, the Properties tab has an event button. It shows me all the possible events I can wire up to a delegate for the control that has focus. Then, all I have to do is double-click my event of choice and VS will auto-stub the delegate for me with the appropriate EventArgs type and everything. It'll then automagically take me to that delegate in the class.

How can I do the same thing in ASP.NET? For example, where can I click or double-click to have VS auto-stub in lifecycle Page events such as OnInit or OnUnload and then take me to the newly stubbed delegate? Surely this isn't always a manual process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event tab in the property grid requires that Design View be up to date (synchronized) to work.  For this to happen, you either need to be in design view, or have just left it without making changes to the document (or be in split view, so you can refresh the designer easily at will).

See also: [Events tab randomly appears and disappears in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764590/events-tab-randomly-appears-and-disappears-in-vs-2008/3172497#3172497)

Adding information from the comments:

Currently (VS2010), the only stubbing support for event handler generation using WebForms is for server control events.  There isn't any tooling out-of-the-box to create event handlers for the Page itself (e.g. OnInit, OnUnload) if you're using code-behind files.  However, if you are using single file webforms (i.e. no code behind) you can generate these via the Navigation Bar (disabled by default in VS2010, but enabled in previous versions).

Comment: Yep, knew that much. Thank you. I'm specifically looking for how to hook up Page events. What say you?

Comment: Page events are a different beast.  I don't know of a way to stub them out if you're using code behind pages.  If you're not using code behind pages, you can use the HTML editor's Navigation Bar (disabled by default in VS2010, you can turn it on under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML).  Also, might be worthwhile to file a feature request at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualStudio/

Comment: Just checked with one of the devs for the HTML editor, and he verified that there isn't any tooling for Page event handlers presently (aside from generating Page_Load by double clicking in the designer).  Connect is probably your best bet to get this changed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the element, go to event tab in property grid. Then double click the event you want.

Also make sure you are using "runat=server" and ASP.NET WebControls. In other words, not HTML controls.

Comment: There is no event tab in the property grid specifically for the Page. That's the problem.  {-o)

How do I bring the Page itself into context?

Comment: Well that is a problem! What control are you using? Are you sure you are inside an ASPX page?

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the question: Please see Jimmy's comments above. Looks like everything else works fine but there's no method of auto-wiring up Page-type-specific events.