# Move out of form control in visual studio?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I have a project in Visual Studio in which some controls like buttons, labels are added and events are specified on specific activity. From the event, how to check the button/ control for which this event is fired?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562712/wheres-the-dropdown-list-of-events-in-visual-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on a control on your form and click on the lightning bolt in the picture, you can see all events that are tied to that control.

[image]

Comment: But I am trying reverse. I am in code of form events and I am trying to get the form button on which this event is fired.

Comment: If you right click the event and hit `Find All References` you'll see a line something like this: `btnButton.Click += new ClickEventHandler(YourMethod);` which means your method is wired to btnButton's Click on the form.

Comment: Thanks. That answers the question.